# Mysql group by column and get max id preferably on another column value

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with the content like this;

```
id      customer  is_default
1606384 5828      1
1573786 5828      0
1575316 5828      0
1817769 5828      0
```

For this customer, there is a **is_default=1** address but some others there is none. For example;

```
id      customer  is_default
1806384 5829      0
1873786 5829      0
1875316 5829      0
1917769 5829      0
```

I'd like to get the **MAX(id)** but query should prefer **is_default=1** first

So for example, in the first table query must return **MAX(id) = 1606384** and for the second table should return **MAX(id) = 1917769**

I can't wrap my head around this.

Can you guys help me ?

## Edit 1

Responding to comment of @Strawberry

I've tried this approach;

First I've multiplied the **is_default** with **id** and order by in order to get the max id from the query. But this was all wrong as now I understand

```
    SELECT MAX(id) as mid,MAX(is_default)
    FROM (
        (SELECT rel.maxid as id,customer,is_default FROM (
select (id+(is_default*10000000)) as maxid,customer,is_default FROM customer_address ORDER BY is_default DESC) rel ORDER BY maxid)
             ) rel
    GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,customer INT NOT NULL
,is_default TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1606384,5828,1),
(1573786,5828,0),
(1575316,5828,0),
(1817769,5828,0),
(1806384,5829,0),
(1873786,5829,0),
(1875316,5829,0),
(1917769,5829,0);

SELECT x.customer
     , COALESCE(MAX(y.id),MAX(x.id)) id 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.customer = x.customer 
   AND y.is_default = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY x.customer;
+----------+---------+
| customer | id      |
+----------+---------+
|     5828 | 1606384 |
|     5829 | 1917769 |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Quite brilliant to be honest ! Great job !

Comment: This is a brilliant approach. Thank you. It solved my problem

Comment: @paroxit do you really prefer a self join of the table and then aggregate when you can simply aggregate?

Comment: @Gosfly this is not brilliant. It's awful. A self join for a relatively large table when all that is needed is conditional aggregation could prove it as that.

Comment: @forpas Good point when considering large table. But when I try your approach and Strawberry 's approach results are the same. For Strawberry 's query "500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 100 ms (execution: 82 ms, fetching: 18 ms)" , and for yours "500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 100 ms (execution: 81 ms, fetching: 19 ms)"... Execution is roughly the same

Comment: @paroxit there may exist many solutions for the same problem. You chose the worst solution. A self join is not needed. All you need is aggregation. And remember that all tables start with 1 row and then they grow. Try both solutions with a large table.

Comment: Goodness me. Calm down.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following but @Strawberry answer seems way better :

```
SELECT 
  customer, 
  (CASE WHEN is_default IS NOT NULL THEN is_default ELSE nis_default END) AS max
FROM (
SELECT 
  customer, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN is_default = 1 THEN id END) AS is_default, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN is_default = 0 THEN id END) AS nis_default
FROM t
GROUP BY customer) T
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e41b23618a9e891547bdf826a040f34c)

EDIT : My query can be simplified with COALESCE like this :

```
SELECT 
  customer, 
  COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE WHEN is_default = 1 THEN id END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN is_default = 0 THEN id END)) AS max
FROM t
GROUP BY customer
```

[**SECOND DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=589ce2850ff242596f683787a2bd1d02)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that @Strawberry 's solution seems to be working fine..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want single max(id) value, preferably with is_default=1, then use:

```
select max_id
from (
  select is_default, max(id) as  max_id
  from customer_address
  group by is_default
  order by is_default desc
  limit 1
) as q;
```

Comment: This only returns one value

Comment: Yes, it was bit unclear if @paroxit wanted single value or multiple values. Understood from the example that (s)he wanted a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CASE expression:

```
select 
  customer, 
  case max(is_default) 
    when 1 then max(is_default * id) 
    else max(id)
  end maxid
from tablename 
group by customer
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCKW9HUjqKz5wogrPA4PpY/0).
Results:

```
| customer | maxid   |
| -------- | ------- |
| 5828     | 1606384 |
| 5829     | 1917769 |
```